# Symbol/String Interchangeable Object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need an object that takes a string or symbol (then converts it into a string) and can be compared to either a string or symbol interchangeably similar to how HashWithIndifferent access behaves:

```
StringWithIndifferentAccess.new("foo").include? :f
=> true

StringWithIndifferentAccess.new(:foo) ==  "foo"
=> true
```

Is there an easy way to do this and have it "just work"(TM) without having to manually re-define every string method?

Comment: @steenslag I was wrong. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 3):

This passes on your examples

```
class StringWithIndifferentAccess
  def initialize obj
    @string = obj.to_s
  end

  def == (other)
    @string == other.to_s
  end

  def include?(other)
    @string.include? other.to_s
  end
end
```

---

### Update

So I just read the question again and to "just work" for all string methods you could use method_missing and convert any symbol to a string like so:

```
class StringWithIndifferentAccess
  def initialize obj
    @string = obj.to_s
  end

  # Seems we have to override the == method because we get it from BasicObject
  def == (other)
    @string == other.to_s
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    args.map! {|arg| arg.is_a?(Symbol) ? arg.to_s : arg }
    if @string.respond_to?(method)
      @string.send(method, *args, &block)
    else
      raise NoMethodError  
    end    
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
sym = :try
sym.class
=> Symbol
str = "try"
str.class
=> String
str.to_sym
=> :try
sym.to_s
=> "try"
```

So just create a class that is constructed using a symbol or a string but also has a value that is always a string. Add a method undefined that takes a single argument, converts it to string and than invokes it on the value.

Hope this will help.